# Docker | Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed | Port is already allocated

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i've been trying all the existing commands for several hours and could not fix this problem.
i used everything covered in this Article: [Docker - Bind for 0.0.0.0:4000 failed: port is already allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176584/docker-bind-for-0-0-0-04000-failed-port-is-already-allocated).

I currently have one container: `docker ps -a` |  meanwhile  `docker ps` is empty

```
    CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
5ebb9289dfd1   dockware/dev:latest   "/bin/bash /entrypoi…"   2 minutes ago   Created             TheGoodPartDocker
```

when i Try `docker-compose up -d` i get the Error:

```
ERROR: for TheGoodPartDocker  Cannot start service shop: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint TheGoodPartDocker (3b59ebe9366bf1c4a848670c0812935def49656a88fa95be5c4a4be0d7d6f5e6): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated
```

I've tried to remove everything using: `docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm`

Or remove ports: `fuser -k 80/tcp`

even deleting networks:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -f /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db
```

or just manually shut down stop and run:

```
docker-compose down
docker stop 5ebb9289dfd1
docker rm 5ebb9289dfd1
```

here is also my netstat : `netstat | grep 80`

```
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20680    /mnt/wslg/PulseAudioRDPSink
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18044
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32780
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17805    /run/guest-services/procd.sock
```

And `docker port TheGoodPartDocker` gives me no result.

I also restarted my computer, but nothing works :(.

Thanks for helping

Comment: could you try `netstat -ntlp | grep 80`?

Comment: The best way to check if its really port issue run your container with different port. like 81 0r 82. If your container runs successfully then you were doing something wrong with flush or something else using port 80.

Comment: @vishnunarayanan this is the result: tcp6    0    0 :::80      :::*      LISTEN      -

Answer (score 0):

Obviously port 80 is already occupied by some other process. You need to stop the process, before you start the container. To find out the process use `ss`:

```
$ ss -tulpn | grep 22
tcp   LISTEN 0      128          0.0.0.0:22         0.0.0.0:*    users:(("sshd",pid=1187,fd=3))                           
tcp   LISTEN 0      128             [::]:22            [::]:*    users:(("sshd",pid=1187,fd=4))
```