# docker not getting up for airflow web server with same port error

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-2.x

Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker-updated-airflow-webserver-1 (bc985183d739d8a5f9ed617c02174c56a691b864f4b239785a6f2ec66bfbae90): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated

> (base) austin.jackson@MAC docker-updated % docker ps | grep 8080
> 5f7fb87cf71f   apache/airflow:2.5.1           "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"
> 4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes (healthy)   8080/tcp
> docker-updated-airflow-scheduler-1 871b26067f59   apache/airflow:2.5.1
> "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes (healthy)
> 8080/tcp
> docker-updated-airflow-triggerer-1 ef2ea69fccf8   apache/airflow:2.5.1
> "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes (healthy)
> 8080/tcp
> docker-updated-airflow-worker-1

Please help, how to solve this problem

```
(base) austin.jackson@MAC ~ % sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
Password:
COMMAND    PID              USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd      1              root    8u  IPv6 0xb09765236eb15ed      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd      1              root    9u  IPv4 0xb09765236ebe10d      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd      1              root   11u  IPv6 0xb09765236eb15ed      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd      1              root   12u  IPv4 0xb09765236ebe10d      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
PanGPS    1043              root    7u  IPv4 0xb0976523ddf610d      0t0  TCP localhost:4767 (LISTEN)
redis-ser 1049 austin.jackson    6u  IPv4 0xb0976523ddf96f5      0t0  TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN)
redis-ser 1049 austin.jackson    7u  IPv6 0xb09765236eb0f8d      0t0  TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN)
mysqld    1248 austin.jackson   18u  IPv4 0xb0976523ddf7f55      0t0  TCP localhost:33060 (LISTEN)
mysqld    1248 austin.jackson   20u  IPv4 0xb0976523ddf753d      0t0  TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)
com.netsk 1377              root   13u  IPv4 0xb097652445c753d      0t0  TCP localhost:57130 (LISTEN)
Microsoft 1474 austin.jackson   19u  IPv6 0xb09765236eb1c4d      0t0  TCP localhost:42050 (LISTEN)
com.docke 1714 austin.jackson   40u  IPv4 0xb0976524514753d      0t0  TCP *:49410 (LISTEN)
com.docke 1714 austin.jackson  170u  IPv6 0xb09765236eb428d      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
com.docke 1714 austin.jackson  171u  IPv6 0xb09765236eb35cd      0t0  TCP *:9092 (LISTEN)
com.docke 1714 austin.jackson  172u  IPv6 0xb09765236eb2f6d      0t0  TCP *:9102 (LISTEN)
com.docke 1714 austin.jackson  173u  IPv6 0xb0976524cf4b5cd      0t0  TCP *:9125 (LISTEN)
com.docke 1714 austin.jackson  174u  IPv6 0xb09765236eb3c2d      0t0  TCP *:2376 (LISTEN)
vpnkit-br 1765 austin.jackson   11u  IPv4 0xb0976524514753d      0t0  TCP *:49410 (LISTEN)
(base) austin.jackson@MAC ~ %
```

Even tried to update the docker file to execute specific script

`> base) austin.jackson@MAC docker-updated % docker-compose up` > airflow-webserver [+] Running 4/4  ⠿ Container docker-updated-redis-1
`> Running`                                                                > 0.0s  ⠿ Container docker-updated-postgres-1           Running                                                                                                         0.0s  ⠿ Container docker-updated-airflow-init-1       Created                                                                                                         0.0s  ⠿ Container docker-updated-airflow-webserver-1  Created                                                                                                         0.1s Attaching to docker-updated-airflow-webserver-1 Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on
`> endpoint docker-updated-airflow-webserver-1` > (7d284efe9faa438f8e22d2a1d0db027957e6e1b2ab3d241a6c6a93aa8fcbb045):
`> Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated (base)` > austin.jackson@UG-GW-MAC60 docker-updated % docker stop
`> 7d284efe9faa438f8e22d2a1d0db027957e6e1b2ab3d241a6c6a93aa8fcbb045`  Error
`> response from daemon: No such container:` > `7d284efe9faa438f8e22d2a1d0db027957e6e1b2ab3d241a6c6a93aa8fcbb045` > (base) austin.jackson@UG-GW-MAC60 docker-updated % docker rm
`>` 7d284efe9faa438f8e22d2a1d0db027957e6e1b2ab3d241a6c6a93aa8fcbb045
`> Error: No such container:` > `7d284efe9faa438f8e22d2a1d0db027957e6e1b2ab3d241a6c6a93aa8fcbb045` > (base) austin.jackson@UG-GW-MAC60 docker-updated % docker rm -f
`>` 7d284efe9faa438f8e22d2a1d0db027957e6e1b2ab3d241a6c6a93aa8fcbb045
`> Error: No such container:` > `7d284efe9faa438f8e22d2a1d0db027957e6e1b2ab3d241a6c6a93aa8fcbb045` > (base) austin.jackson@MAC docker-updated %

Comment: It seems like something is already using the 8080 port but not docker from the logs you shared. Maybe check the output of `sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` for any programs using 8080?

Comment: Updated the command output...

Comment: That is indeed odd, seems like no active processes on 8080. I've found an older SO post where someone had a port already allocated error from docker with no container running. [This answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62857591/20963694) might help? I'd first try restarting docker, then try `docker network prune` (note: this will remove all old networks no active containers are using).