# Docker port is already allocated but the port is not allocated

Tags: docker, port

Claiming at the first:The solution in [Docker - Bind for 0.0.0.0:4000 failed: port is already allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176584/docker-bind-for-0-0-0-04000-failed-port-is-already-allocated) isn't work on my computer.

And i'll use a screenshot to explain what I've tried

OS:Windows 11 Pro Workstation Build 22621.1413
Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243

[image: What I've Done]

Answer (score 2):

Use command to see which container is already using 4000 port

```
docker ps -a
```

Get the container name or container id which is using that port and Now delete that container

```
docker rm container_id
```

Now create again that container